# How to evaluate this limit involving matrices?

Tags: matrices, limits, recurrence-relations

We are given $$a_{ij}(n)=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1\\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}^n$$
And we have to evaluate $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{12}(n)}{a_{22}(n)}$$

Now I tried to evaluate the first few powers and found the relations: 
$a_{12}(n)=2a_{22}(n)+a_{22}(n-1)$

$a_{11}(n)=2a_{12}(n)+a_{12}(n-1)$

But I can't relate these for finding the limit.
Can someone guide me further or perhaps provide an alternate way?

Comment: Hint: diagonalize the matrix first

Comment: Do you mean $a(n)$ (as opposed to $a_{ij}(n)$) is defined by that expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $A$ can be diagonalized as it has two distinct eigenvalues $1 \pm \sqrt{2}$. 
$$A=PDP^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
-\sqrt{2}+1 & \sqrt{2}+1 \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \, \, \begin{bmatrix}
-\sqrt{2}+1 & 0 \\
0 & \sqrt{2}+1
\end{bmatrix}\,\, \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{4} & \frac{\sqrt{2}+2}{4} \\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} & \frac{-\sqrt{2}+2}{4}
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Thus
$$A^n=PD^nP^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
-\sqrt{2}+1 & \sqrt{2}+1 \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}  \, \begin{bmatrix}
(-\sqrt{2}+1)^n & 0 \\
0 & (\sqrt{2}+1)^n
\end{bmatrix}\, \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{4} & \frac{\sqrt{2}+2}{4} \\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} & \frac{-\sqrt{2}+2}{4}
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Now you can get expressions for $a_{12}(n)$ and $a_{22}(n)$ to compute the given limit.

Comment: I'm sorry but we haven't covered eigenvalues etc yet... What does diagonalizing a matrix mean?

Comment: @infinite-blank- diagonalizing  a matrix means being able to write the matrix in the form of $PDP^{-1}$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix and $P$ is an invertible matrix.

Comment: Oh I see... So then how are we able to use the exponentiation step that you have done?

Comment: @infinite-blank- consider $A^2=(PDP^{-1})(PDP^{-1})$. Now use the associativity of the matrix multiplication to get $A^2=(PD)P^{-1}P(DP^{-1})=PDIDP^{-1}=PD^2P^{-1}$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

If you diagonalize, you will have $P^{-1}AP=D\implies A^n=PD^nP^{-1}$.